# Migrating on-premise server with RAID1 to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, mdadm

I have an on-premise physical server running Debian 10 that I would like to migrate to AWS EC2. The server storage consists of two 1TB HDD drives on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` that have been set up as a RAID1 array with `mdadm`. Most of the capacity of the array is unused as I only have about 60GB of data on the server.

The server is running a lot of legacy software that I would prefer not to have to set up from scratch on a fresh instance, so I tried to use the AWS Application Migration Service for a quick and easy lift-and-shift which has worked great for me in the past. However, the EC2 instance refuses to start with the error message `Client.InternalError: Client error on launch`. I followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-client-internal-error/) but the drives were both attached and seem to be in a healthy state.

One thing I did notice is that EC2 wants to mount the other volume to `/dev/sda1`. The RAID array has two volumes:

- `/dev/md0` is the boot volume and uses `/dev/hda2` and `/dev/hdb2`
- `/dev/md2` holds the root file system and uses `/dev/hda4` and `/dev/hdb4`.

I tried to detach the volume mounted as `/dev/hda1` and reattach it as `/dev/hda` but EC2 doesn't allow that:

> Value (/dev/sda) for parameter device is invalid. /dev/sda is not a
> valid EBS device name.

Is there a way to get this working or do I just have to bite the bullet and try to manually migrate all the services I set up in the Debian Etch era to a fresh instance?

Edit: Here's the output of `fdisk -l`, `df` and `mdadm`:

```
me@mybox ~ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3904748        0   3904748   0% /dev
tmpfs             791100    82712    708388  11% /run
/dev/md2       952731676 58111432 846197444   7% /
tmpfs            3955496        0   3955496   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            3955496        0   3955496   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0          468009    80478    362562  19% /boot
tmpfs             791096        0    791096   0% /run/user/1000

me@mybox ~ $ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD1002FBYS-5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EFCE7E13-5FF6-4EEE-9E5F-BCE87C01BE67

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2      4096    1003519     999424   488M Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3   1003520   17004543   16001024   7.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb4  17004544 1953523711 1936519168 923.4G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD1002FBYS-5
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 128EBD01-6A5E-4928-8B3A-010A11B3DFEA

Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2      4096    1003519     999424   488M Linux RAID
/dev/sda3   1003520   17004543   16001024   7.6G Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  17004544 1953523711 1936519168 923.4G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/md0: 487.7 MiB, 511377408 bytes, 998784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 7.6 GiB, 8188264448 bytes, 15992704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 923.3 GiB, 991363399680 bytes, 1936256640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

me@mybox ~ $ sudo mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Jul 27 23:21:40 2013
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 499392 (487.69 MiB 511.38 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 499392 (487.69 MiB 511.38 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Aug 27 06:27:46 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : mybox:0  (local to host mybox)
              UUID : (redacted)
            Events : 376

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       18        0      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Are you trying to set up a raid in a VM instance? Why?

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to move the whole thing away from its current home. Best case would have been to just turn the 1TB raid array to an 80GB SSD volume but the migration tool refused to create an image at filesystem level and wanted to scan the physical drives instead.

Comment: Fsarchive, clonezilla, tar?

Answer (score 2):

Googled:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2297594-can-we-migrate-a-physical-server-to-aws-if-yes-then-how-please-help

There is a small and excellent free tool that is capable of doing this called V2V Converter https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter. Run it on the target system, specify the entire disk as a source, and provide your AWS credentials as the target. The tool will do the rest.

Basically, that will be a P2V conversion, and the server is migrated "as is". Make sure you are aware of the specifics and know what you are doing

Comment: That's a Windows desktop software that won't run on a non-VM Debian. Besides, the AWS Application Migration Service does exactly that but didn't work as intended on a RAID based system, hence this question.

Comment: Are you looking for P2V tool you can run on Linux or what?

Comment: I already have one, provided by AWS. It scans all my drives at block level and creates EC2 snapshots of them. However, EC2 can't boot up using them for reasons explained in my question.

Comment: Just backup filesystems with tar and restore it in AWS